# Combine 3 tables based on timestamp into one new table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables that contain different data. All tables have a DATETIME timestamp. I would like to create a new table where all data of a certain timestamp is stored in a single row.

So all tables have a column "timestamp" and all tables have different columns. After combining I would like to have one table with again "timestamp" and the columns of all tables collected in one row.

I am working in MS-SQL

Comment: Please post table definitions and sample data.

Comment: if you wanna work again with the 3 existing tables, use a view instead of a new table. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one of the tables has all the timestamps you can do:

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.timestamp = t2.timestamp
LEFT JOIN t3 ON t3.timestamp = t1.timestamp
```

Otherwise you might have to do something like:

```
SELECT t1.*,t2.*.t3.*
FROM (SELECT timestamp
      FROM t1
      UNION
      SELECT timestamp
      FROM t2
      UNION
      SELECT timestamp
      FROM t3
) t0
LEFT JOIN t1 ON t0.timestamp = t1.timestamp
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t0.timestamp = t2.timestamp
LEFT JOIN t3 ON t0.timestamp = t3.timestamp
```

First part gets all possible timestamps and LEFT JOINS them with the 3 tables. You may massage a little the columns selected to not return duplicate timestamp columns